# When I edit my html table to update, my inputs are not detected and only the word Array and number 1 is displayed and updated to my database

Tags: php, html, arrays

So I'm working on this table on which the user can edit and remove a row if he wants to. I used input `type="text"` in the cells so it can be edited but when ever I edit the cells all i get is the word array and the number 1. Remove button is working fine though. I think it has something to do with the array on the names and id's I assigned in the inputs. I'm using firefox for this. Can it not determine the arrays I've assigned or should I be using a different method of assigning names and id's?

This is my code for the table:

```
<form action="includes/menuMutliple-script.php" method="post">
<?php
require 'includes/database-link.php';
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `menu` ORDER BY `menu`.`Menu_Type` ASC ");

echo "<table id='table' border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Menu ID</th>
<th>Menu Type</th>
<th>Menu</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Menu_ID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' id='typeUp[]' name='typeUp[]' value='".$row['Menu_Type']."'> </td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' id='menuUp[]' name='menuUp[]' value='".$row['Menu']."'> </td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' id='priceUp[]' name='priceUp[]' value='".$row['Price']."'> </td>";
echo "<td><div class='remove'><button name='remove' id='remove' onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Please confirm deletion');\" value='".$row['Menu_ID']."' >Remove</button></div></td>";
echo "<td><div class='update'><button name='update' id='update' onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Please confirm update');\" value='".$row['Menu_ID']."' >Update</button></div></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>

</form>
```

This is my php for update:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['remove'])){
require 'database-link.php';
$id = $_POST['remove'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM menu WHERE Menu_ID=?";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
header("Location: ../menu-form.php?error=sqlerror");
exit();
    }
            else {                                
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        header("Location: ../menu-form.php?menudeletion=success");
                exit();
            }
 mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysql_close($conn);
}
else if (isset($_POST['update'])){

require 'database-link.php';

$update = $_POST['update'];
$type = $_POST['typeUp'];
$menu = $_POST['menuUp'];
$price = $_POST['priceUp'];

$sql = "UPDATE menu SET Menu_Type=?, Menu=?, Price=? WHERE Menu_ID=?";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        header("Location: ../menu-form.php?error=sqlerror");
        exit();
    }
 else {

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssdi", $type, $menu, $price, $update);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        header("Location: ../menu-form.php?menu&update=success");
                exit();
            }
 mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysql_close($conn);

}
else {
header("Location: ../menu-form.php");
exit();
}
```

This is the table:

[Display Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC80f.jpg)

I'm still new in php so please go easy on me.

Comment: Your update is causing the problem - you bind `$type` as the value, but set it as `$type = $_POST['typeUp'];`.  In your form you potentially have an array of values, so you would need to loop over this array and process 1 row at a time.  Your database is probably already updated incorrectly, so you will need to correct that as well.

Comment: I dont really know what you mean, I'm just watching tutorials to learn. I'm totally new at this. I'm sorry. They say that adding [] will make an array automatically in php, I think I'm doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Considering your code, If you concatenate an `array` with `string` it will just output "`Array`" (use instead `join(' ', $your_array_here)` if you need it as `string`).

And as I noticed, your code expects a single row but the HTML-form does not work like that (at least not without custom AJAX script) and sends you all rows;
To fix it your frontend should pass both the row-index and menu-id to the backend (for `Update` only since `Remove` seems to not need that), for example like:

```php
<form action="includes/menuMutliple-script.php" method="post">
  <?php
  require 'includes/database-link.php';
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `menu` ORDER BY `menu`.`Menu_Type` ASC ");

  echo "<table id='table' border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Menu ID</th>
<th>Menu Type</th>
<th>Menu</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>";

  $index = 0;
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Menu_ID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' id='typeUp-$index' name='typeUp[]' value='".$row['Menu_Type']."'> </td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' id='menuUp-$index' name='menuUp[]' value='".$row['Menu']."'> </td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' id='priceUp-$index' name='priceUp[]' value='".$row['Price']."'> </td>";
    echo "<td><div class='remove'><button name='remove' id='remove-$index' onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Please confirm deletion');\" value='${row['Menu_ID']}' >Remove</button></div></td>";
    echo "<td><div class='update'><button name='update' id='update-$index' onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Please confirm update');\" value='$index&${row['Menu_ID']}' >Update</button></div></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    ++$index;
  }
  echo "</table>";
  mysqli_close($conn);
  ?>

</form>
```

And your backend (the destination sat as `action`) should find the row it needs using the `$index`, something like:

```php
<?php
if (isset($_POST['remove'])) {
  require 'database-link.php';
  $id = $_POST['remove'];
  $sql = "DELETE FROM menu WHERE Menu_ID=?";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("Location: ../menu-form.php?error=sqlerror");
    exit();
  } else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    header("Location: ../menu-form.php?menudeletion=success");
  }
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  mysql_close($conn);
  exit();
} else if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

  require 'database-link.php';

  $command = explode('&', $_POST['update']);
  $index =  $command[0];
  $menu_id =  $command[1];
  $type = $_POST['typeUp'][$index];
  $menu = $_POST['menuUp'][$index];
  $price = $_POST['priceUp'][$index];

  $sql = "UPDATE menu SET Menu_Type=?, Menu=?, Price=? WHERE Menu_ID=?";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("Location: ../menu-form.php?error=sqlerror");
  } else {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssdi", $type, $menu, $price, $menu_id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    header("Location: ../menu-form.php?menu&update=success");
  }
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  mysql_close($conn);
  exit();
} else {
  header("Location: ../menu-form.php");
  exit();
}
```

> **Note:** both `$index` and `menu-id` are combined as the update button's value and the backend later extracts both pieces of information using `explode(...)`.

Comment: I got rid of the brackets and it did update but it just copied the value of different cell and then updated, now i have cells that have the same value

Comment: @Mike964, updated answer! (consider accepting when it is helpful).

Comment: I did your code and it does not copy the value of other cells anymore but it just displays the same value. I'm guessing since the the assign value is  $row, it just copies the value and display it back. Maybe an if statement for onKeypress in javascript might work, where if you type it will not display the $row value anymore

Comment: I kind of don't get what you mean, but either you should change the frontend and use `JavaScript` to override the `Update` button (which currently does just submit the entire form, I recently posted an [single file example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58407651/8740349) about how to do that), Or, maybe you should use one single Save-button (instead of multiple Update-buttons) because the whole form is posted anyway.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that whatever data I put in the mysql table, it never changes when i update. It just returns the previous value. That's why I'm guessing it's because the value I've assign to it is the data from the sql table. The update is working but the value will be fixed sinced it's just going to update what value was assigned to it. I'll check out the post you've made. Thanks a lot for the advice