# How to POST data to a backend server to store into database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to store below div data into my database.

```
<div id="myContent" contenteditable="true">This is a simple text</div>
```

Give me any example how I can POST this data into a database.

Comment: 1. Use Jquery Ajax function 2. you can make this div as <textarea>

Comment: you need to parse it with preg_match or Crawler, or you can make Ajax POST request with that div parsed data

Comment: **Mukesh** Can you demonstrate with a small example i don't want to use <textarea> or <input> tags just <div> data store into database...

Comment: **Viszman** i don't know much about Ajax so give a small example... thanks both guy's in advance

Comment: Please see , [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  ?

Comment: @ErMantuSuna, make sure you mark the answer which helped you as answered. Which will help the users who visit the question in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to:

1. Extract the data from the `div` using `JavaScript`
2. Include it in your POST request.
3. Catch and handle the request in `PHP` to store it in the Database.

#### Example:

This is a single *PHP* file sample (without full page refresh), but you may need to change the part `DATABASE_NAME_HERE` and also `root` (which is the user-name).

```php
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  // Escape possible HTML tags:
  $content = htmlspecialchars($_POST['myContent'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE);

  // Database connection.
  $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=DATABASE_NAME_HERE', 'root', '');
  $db->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_table` (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, text VARCHAR(1024))');

  // Storing new record.
  $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (NULL, :text)');
  $query->bindValue(':text', $content);
  if ($query->execute()) {
    $response = 'Successfully stored: ' . $content;
  }
  else {
    $response = 'Error: ' . join(' ', $query->errorInfo());
  }

  exit($response);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>My title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('form#my_form_id').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      const content = $('#myContent').text();
      $.post('#', {submit: true, myContent: content}, function(response) {
        alert(response);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="center" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 150px;">
    <div id="myContent" contenteditable="true">This is simple text</div>

    <form id="my_form_id">
        <input name="username">
        <input type="submit" name="Send">
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

> **Note:** if you want to store the entire HTML of the `div` and not just its text in above:
>
> 1. Change the part `$('#myContent').text()` to `$('#myContent').html()`.
> 2. Remove the `htmlspecialchars(...)` method usage (e.g. `$content = $_POST['myContent'];`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to communicate with servers.

> Use XMLHttpRequest (XHR) objects to interact with servers. You can retrieve data from a URL without having to do a full page refresh. This enables a Web page to update just part of a page without disrupting what the user is doing. XMLHttpRequest is used heavily in AJAX programming.

Here is an example

```
// Read your data inside the HTML DIV using the ID
var content = document.getElementById('myContent').innerHTML;
// Add the contents to the object which you want to send to the backend
var data = { "myContent": content };

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 

var theUrl = "/json-handler"; // The backend URL which expects your data
xmlhttp.open("POST", theUrl);

// Set the request format
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

// JSON encode the data by stringifying it before sending to the server
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    let myData=$('#myContent').html();
    $.ajax({
            method:'POST',
            url : 'put your file path where do want to handle data',
            data:{
                'data':myData 
                },
            success:function(returnMsg){
            console.log("Success Msg",returnMsg)
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use AJAX send your data (if you need more info, see it: [Introduction to Ajax - IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ajaxintro1/index.html))

so:

1. Get your DOM data -- use javascript code;
2. Send your data to server API;
3. Server save the data.

xmlHttp / jQuery AJAX / Axios / etc. you can choice anyone AJAX tool.

Answer (score 0):

> **Part1 Send data**
>   1 Step: Get the Value of your id = myContent     2 Step: The url where
>   you want to send the value 3 Step: pass the object 4 Make an Callback
>   forurself to see if it was successful

```
<script> 
            $.ajax({
                //1 Step
                var data = $('#myContent').val(),
                //2 Step
                url 'theUrlWhereYouWantToSend',
                //3 Step
                data: {data:data},
                //4 Step
                sucess: function hello(){
                 console.log("Transfering Data was sucessful"};

            });
            </script>
```

> If u have problems pls see on your Browser Console on register
>   "Network" if it sends to ur url (the url where u want to pass the
>   data)
>
> **> Part2 insert into database**
>
> 1 Step: Connect database

```
    $localhost = ""; ->ur localhost
    $password =""; ->ur Password
    $username = "root"; ->Ur username
    $db = "database"; ->Name of ur database (not table DATABASE)
```

If u never changed someting than use exactly my code change only database name

**Part 3 Get the data into PHP**

```
if(!emtpty($_POST['myContent']){
 $newVariable = $_POST['myContent'];
}
```

**> Part 4 Connect database (PHP)**

```
$link = mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $password, $db);
```

> 3 Control

```
if(!$link){
 echo "Connection Failed";
}
```

> 3 Step: Insert into database your file

```
$query = "insert into URTABLENAME (ColumnName) values ('$newVariable')
```

> 4 Step: Send Query to ur database

```
$sql = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

> 5 Step Check

```
var_dump($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

`<div id="myContent" contenteditable="true">This is a simple text</div>`

**Jquery :**

```
var data = $("#myContent").html();
var url = "--your url here--";
$.post(url,
  {
    html: data
  },
  function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

**PHP**

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "dbusername", "dbpass", "dbname");
$html_data = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["html"]);
mysqli_query($db, "INESRT INTO MYTABLE(html_data) VALUES('$html_data')");
```

Answer (score -1):

I am going to give a generic answer here because I am not sure how I can be more specific. There is a couple of steps that need to happen here. But first, decide what exactly is the data you need? Then...

1. You should be able to access the DOMElement in code.
2. You can create an object with the data that you need to send to the server
3. You can open an API on the server if there isnt one already
4. You can then send a HTTP POST request with the object as the payload at the particular API endpoint
5. You will have to write code on the server to handle the actual persistence to the DB

Comment: small example please how to do with code...thnx

Comment: Ok, can you answer what information you would like to store in the database? For Steps 3 and 5, the kind of server and db you are using is also relevant

Answer (score -1):

follow the steps below

1. get the data from div using JavaScript
2. send the data to the server using ajax calls for storing into ur database

(I have assumed that ur Jquery is already defined)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('myContent');

//// ajax calls to the server

</script>
```